# Need to load jQuery UI Tabs dynamic content links through Ajax

Tags: jquery, jquery-dialog, jquery-tabs, dynamic-links

I have this jQuery UI Tabs model with only 2 tabs and I need the content to load through Ajax. The problem is that these tabs are loaded inside a jQuery UI Dialog and `mid` is dynamic. I mean, the dialog is launched by clicking a link (which contains `mid=X`).

The code is something like this:

**Javascript:**

```
$('.item-movie-link').each(function() {
    $(this).parent().click(function() {
        $('#tabs-movie li a[href$=info]').attr('href', $(this).attr('href') + '&op=info');
        $('#tabs-movie li a[href$=cast]').attr('href', $(this).attr('href') + '&op=cast');

        $('#dialog-movie-info').dialog('open');
        $('#tabs-movie').tabs();

        return false;
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="dialog-movie-info">
  <div id="tabs-movie">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#tab-info"><img src="template/images/icon-tab-movie-info.png" alt="" />Information</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab-cast"><img src="template/images/icon-tab-movie-cast.png" alt="" />Cast List</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

This works when I first click one of those `.item-movie-link`'s, but after closing the dialog and clicking another link, it will not work, the same information will be displayed.

How can I make this work? Maybe there's a better approach for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was fixed by destroying the jQuery UI Tabs on the `close` event of the jQuery UI Dialog:

```
$('#tabs-movie').tabs('destroy');
```